# how i can add animation to any UI by snapkit by swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, snapkit

```
label.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in

        make.width.equalTo(box).dividedBy(2)

        make.top.equalTo(100)

        make.left.greaterThanOrEqualTo(box.snp.left).offset(15)
}
```

I want animate this `label` to another position by `button`

Comment: To quote multi-line code blocks you can put 4 spaces at the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you update your constraints call layoutIfNeeded() on your view in an animation closure.

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0, options: [], animations: { () -> Void in 
       self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.